# How to end long table in Rmd pdf with double line

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra, longtable

In Rmd knit to pdf we found out we can end a table with a double line like this:

```
tibble(v1 = c(1:2),v2 = c(1:2)) %>%
   kable(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(2, hline_after = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(3, hline_after = TRUE)
```

When we want to use this for a table that continues on the next page, with use of:

```
tibble(v1 = c(1:2),v2 = c(1:2)) %>%
   kable(booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"),
                position = "left") %>%
  row_spec(2, hline_after = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(3, hline_after = TRUE)
```

we see an unwanted * between the two lines. Does anyone know why the * appears, or have a suggestion how to get rid of the *, or a better solution to have a double line at the end of a table? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want this double line? The idea of the `booktabs` package is to avoid double lines and use thicker lines before and after the table.

Comment: I did not know that. I am fairly new to LateX, and just observed that booktabs got rid of the vertical lines, so I thought it was an option.. I will read up on the package booktabs. Thank you.